# Error for gradle build for my Java project

Tags: java, gradle, classpath, build.gradle

I am trying to build the Java project located at here: https://github.com/garlicPasta/dotServer

I'm new to Gradle. I downloaded the latest Gradle now (v4.0). I added the `bin` folder of Gradle (which includes `gradle.bat`) to the path so I can run gradle command everywhere. Looks like the project requires Google protobuf which it downloads automatically. But when I start the command `gradle build`, I get the following error:

```
> Configure project :
You are using Gradle 4.0:  This version of the protobuf plugin works with Gradle version 2.12+


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'dotServer'.
> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskInputs.source() is applicable for argument types: (com.google.protobuf.gradle.ProtobufSourceDirectorySet_Decorated) values: [main Proto source]
  Possible solutions: collect(), use([Ljava.lang.Object;)
```

Where is the problem coming from? Can someone try to build the project and let me know?

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that you're using Gradle 4.0, and that the version of the protobuf plugin works with Gradle version 2.12+. Ask the author of this project to use the gradle wrapper, and to commit the wrapper files in the project. That way, you'll just have to checkout the project, and use the gradlew script located at the root of the project to download the appropriate version of gradle automatically and build the project with that version. https://docs.gradle.org/4.0/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: @JBNizet So it says Gradle version +2.12 is needed. 4 is newer than 2.12. Isn't that what `+` means?!

Comment: 2.12+ most probably means 2.x where x is at least equal to 12. Maybe it could work with 3.x, but you need to test. That's why a project should always use the gradle wrapper.

Comment: @JBNizet Ok. Let me test with 2.xx then. Can we install several Gradle versions on a single machine?! Which one to add to the path then?!

Comment: Again: use the gradle wrapper.

Answer (score 5):

I just upgraded to Android Studio 3 and had the same problem when I upgrade Gradle and it's plugin.

We use Google's Protobuf which was included in build.gradle with version 0.7.6. I just changed to 0.8.3 and it builds now.

```
buildscript {
...
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.3'
    }
}
```